# Cannot figure out how to save watermarked picture into separate file with python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create simple GUI to make a watermark on chosen picture. All is working as expected but the problem is when I try to save watermarked picture into a file. Here is my code below

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFont, ImageDraw


image_obj = None
new_image_obj = None


# FUNCTIONS
def open_picture():
    global image_obj
    """Open picture from file explorer"""
    filetype = [("Image File", ".jpg")]
    picture_path = fd.askopenfilename(
        filetypes=filetype,
    )
    image_obj = Image.open(picture_path)

    picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_obj)

    selected_picture = Label(image=picture)
    selected_picture.image = picture
    selected_picture.grid(row=2, columnspan=3)

    return image_obj


def add_watermark(image):
    global new_image_obj
    """Add watermark to the picture"""
    new_image_obj = image
    width, height = new_image_obj.size
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(new_image_obj)

    # Font size and style
    font_size = int(width / 8)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", font_size)

    # Coordinates for the watermark
    x, y = int(width / 2), int(height / 2)

    # Draw watermark
    draw.text((x, y), watermark_entry.get(), font=font, fill="#FFF", anchor="ms")

    new_picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_image_obj)
    selected_picture = Label(image=new_picture)
    selected_picture.image = new_picture
    selected_picture.grid(row=2, columnspan=3)

    return new_image_obj


def save_picture(new_image):
    """Save watermarked picture"""
    filename = fd.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".png", filetypes=(("PNG file", "*.png"), ("All Files",
                                                                                                      "*.*")))
    if not filename:
        return
    new_image.save(filename)


# GUI
window = Tk()
window.title("Picture Watermarking GUI")
window.config(padx=100, pady=50)

open_file = Button(text="Open file", highlightthickness=0, command=open_picture)
open_file.grid(row=0, column=0)

watermark_label = Label(text="Watermark text")
watermark_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

watermark_entry = Entry(width=50)
watermark_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)

watermark_add = Button(text="Add Watermark", highlightthickness=0, command=lambda: add_watermark(image_obj))
watermark_add.grid(row=0, column=1)

save_file = Button(text="Save File", highlightthickness=0, command=lambda: save_picture(new_image_obj))
save_file.grid(row=0, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Trying to save watermarked picture into a file but when saving I have following error:
"When trying to save I'm getting that error: "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes"

Answer (score 2):

You use `fd.asksaveasfile` with `mode='w`' which means you can pass only string to it, not bytes. It looks like `new_image.save(filename)` asks for binary, and since you pass filename to it which is actually IO object (if you want just filename you should use `fd.asksaveasfilename()`) it gives an error because it tries to write binary data to it when "w" mode accepts only string type. So, your solution might be either:

1. `fd.asksaveasfilename()`
2. use `mode='wb'` - b for binary

Comment: Note that `b` means *binary*, not *bytes*.

Comment: Changing to "mode=wb" worked. Thanks!